# Safely renaming/moving files in Node (cross platform)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-system, portability

My goal is to create a function that safely renames files by adding numeric increments if the file is found at the destination, without using a third party library.

Having a source file `foo.bar` and an existing destination `foo.bar` the function would rename using `foo (1).bar`, `foo (2).bar`, `foo (3).bar`, etc.

I have to `fs.lstat()` first because relying on `fs.rename()` failing only works on win32 since linux, darwin will follow the posix conventions and blindly overwrite destination files. I realize there is a non-zero chance that the file could be moved before the rename, unfortunately, I haven't found an asynchronous friendly way to do it.

So this is what I came up with, and it *may* be rather unconventional because I'm relying on a catch() block to do the work.

While this works, I'm leaning on your experience to point out any pitfalls and looking for a better, more syntactically clear way to handle this, advice appreciated!

```
const fs   = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const safe = async (src,dst) => {
    
    let x       = 1
    let target  = dst
    let renamed = false

    while(x < 32) {

        await fs.promises.lstat(target)
        .then(() => target = path.join( path.dirname(dst), path.basename(dst, path.extname(dst)) + ' (' + x + ')' + path.extname(dst) ))
        .catch(async e => {

            console.log(e)
        
            await fs.promises.rename(src,target)
            .then(() => renamed = true)
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
        
        })

        if(renamed === true) break

        x++
    }
    
}

safe('/source/foo.bar','/destination/foo.bar')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On the logical side, having two different conditions to break a loop in two different places makes the code harder to follow. Without changing the flow of the current implementation, why not `while (x < 32 && !renamed) {`, for example? I'd generally avoid using flags at all, in favour of `break` and `continue` (but with the current mix of callbacks that's not an option) and prefer `for` to `while` where the range of values is known up-front.
- `safe` returns a promise that resolves *whatever happens*. Did the file get renamed? Did we run out of numerical suffixes? It's not clear, which means that any caller can't take any action based on the outcome.
- Perhaps most importantly it's clear from the code (and the edits to this question!) is that you don't have a solid understanding of promises. The `async`/`await` syntax and `.then` *are* interoperable, it's all just promises under the hood, but sticking to one or the other makes the code much easier to follow. When nesting promises,

  ```js
  onePromise
    .then(async () => {
      await anotherPromise;
    });
    .then(() => console.log("both done");
  ```

  works because the `.then` callback returns a promise (as `async` functions **always do**) which gets resolved as part of the existing promise chain. So does:

  ```js
  onePromise
    .then(() => {
      return anotherPromise;
    });
    .then(() => console.log("both done");
  ```

  for exactly the same reason, but this won't:

  ```js
  onePromise
    .then(() => {
      anotherPromise;
    });
    .then(() => console.log("both done");
  ```

  because the inner promise isn't part of the outer chain. You can also *use* the chaining, so:

  ```js
  onePromise
    .then(() => 
      return anotherPromise.then((value) => console.log("value"));
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("both done");
    });
  ```

  can be rewritten:

  ```js
  onePromise
    .then(() => 
      return anotherPromise;
    })
    .then((value) => {
      console.log("value")
      console.log("both done");
    });
  ```

---

First, we can extract a function that creates a new destination based on the initial destination and the suffix to add:

```
const addSuffix = (destination, suffix) => {
  const extension = path.extname(destination)
  const filename = path.basename(destination, extension)
  return path.join(
    path.dirname(destination),
    `${filname} (${suffix})${extension}`
  )
}
```

Second, let's tackle the rename of a given source to a destination, *without* worrying about what should happen if that doesn't work out. Note that the `lstat` error is expected (interpreted as "that destination is available") but any error on the `rename` is not expected and left to the caller. This gives three outcomes:

1. promise resolves true: file was renamed
2. promise resolves false: destination was occupied
3. promise rejects: something unexpected went wrong

```
const rename = async (source, destination) => {
  try {
    await fs.promises.lstat(destination)
    return false
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
  await fs.promises.rename(source, destination)
  return true
}
```

Now we can rebuild a much simpler `safe` from these components:

```
const safe = async (source, destination) => {
  let target = destination

  for (let index = 1; index < 32; index++) {
    if (await rename(source, target)) {
      return target
    }
    target = addSuffix(destination, index)
  }

  throw new Error('exhausted all suffixes')
}
```

This has two outcomes:

1. promise resolves: file was (eventually) renamed
2. promise rejects: it wasn't

This lets you provide appropriate feedback to the user:

```
safe('/source/foo.bar','/destination/foo.bar')
  .then((destination) => console.log(`file moved to ${destination}`))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```